What is the movie called, which is based on the story of "Frau Holle" / "Mother Hulda"?
I've been looking for the name of a movie for a long time, but unfortunately the results were unsuccessful. 
I am looking for a movie based on the story of "Frau Holle " / "Mother Hulda" or at least I can remember two scenes from the movie which were taken from the story of "Frau Holle " / "Mother Hulda".

My information about the movie:
If I am not wrong, there is kinda magic in it, so you will see some magic animation (or something this way)
In the film there is an elderly lady who plays the role of "Frau Holle " / "Mother Hulda".
In addition, two sisters (I think they are sisters) are there to prove their deeds,  that they are not lazy (I think). These two "sisters" are teenagers / adults (about 17 - 21 years old, I think). 
The one "sister" is very silly (comparable to the princess from the comedy movie "Disaster Movie"). I think she is shaking completely crazy, without noticing that, the pillow too much that it snows too much afterwards.
The other "sister", who is much more rational than the other, has very much bad luck and / or is unjustly blamed every time (without any intention) because she really tries her best but can't manage it.
If I am not mistaken, these two "sisters" have gone through a portal (maybe a well?) to get into the world of "Frau Holle " / "Mother Hulda". I think they went here because they were told  to learn better behavior or to prove it.
At the very end of the movie (as in the story of "Frau Holle" / "Mother Hulda") the two sisters have to go through a portal. They are rewarded by their deeds. Someone has the chance to get lucky, the other bad luck, but one of the sisters has to experience the good or the bad.
The silly sister, who had luck every time, is rewarded with gold. All her dresses she wore became gold and so she is happy. She could then go back to her world.
"Frau Holle " / "Mother Hulda" says, before the "rational sister" passes through the gate, something like:

"I am so sorry, there is only one last 'price' left".

When the rational sister stood at the gate, she is rewarded with dirt, and everyone thinks that she is completely covered in smelly / dirty stuff. However, she could get away from this "punishment": 
She wore a cape, which she took it to protect herself from getting some dirt. As a viewer you only notice this when all the dirt coming from above disappears. With full pride she returns to "Frau Holle " / "Mother Hulda" and smiles, whereas "Frau Holle " / "Mother Hulda" is happy that she didn't get anything from the dirt.
Finally she also goes back to her world.

These are all memories I have of this movie. If I'm not mistaken, it is a comedy movie, since I remember that I laughed very hard, when the silly sister shook the pillow to hard.
Unfortunately, I don't know about the approximate year and country of the release, but the year of production should be after the year 2000.
I hope you can help me to find the name of this movie, because I would really like to watch this movie again.
EDIT:
I forgot to mention, that it is a real life moviem not an animated movie.
And the movie could also be a fantasy movie.
The language of the movie was in german. But I think the movie was only translated / dubbed.

Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Is it animated ? Because I made some searches and animated movies are coming up.

Thank you very much for your effort! It is a real life movie, I forgot to mention it, sorry for that.

I found a some. Mother Holly from 1961,  Frau Holle (26 min short) from 1971, and a more recant Frau Holle 2008. Here's the IMDb page for the 2008 production, since it's after the 2000 time frame: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1194193/
